# Get frontend baseurl from admin when 'Add Store Code to Urls' to yes

Tags: url, backend, base-url

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560181/how-to-magento-getbaseurl-on-frontend-from-backend), you can fetch baseurl from backend with his code:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
```

This won't work properly, if settings 'Add Store Code to Urls' is set to 'Yes' ([details about that](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41234/in-magento-admin-url-the-word-admin-occurs-twice-how-to-remove-the-second-on)). In this case, it will add 'admin' into url.

I noticed that also

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1)->getProductUrl()
```

won't display proper url, it will add admin into url on fresh Magento installation.

Is that Magento bug? Is there any other proper way to get frontend base url from backend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$storeId = 1; //the store you need the base url:
$homeUrl = Mage::getUrl('', array('_store' => $storeId));
```

For a product url do this:

```
$url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load(1)->getProductUrl();
```

`$storeId` is the same as above.

Comment: I just realized that I should not leave $storeId null because in such case Magento will take current store which is admin when inside backend.